# Backbone.js - each method throw error, while loop the models

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my view - after I fetch the data from collection, I am trying to loop the models using "native" - each method, but I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'each'
```

still I am able to convert my models to json objects..

```
console.log(models.toJSON()); // giving result


models.each(function(model){
    console.log(model); // throw the error.. why..?
})
```

Here is the part of the view where I am consoling:

```
initialize:function(){
    var that = this;
    this.collection = headerCollection;
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.addAll);
    this.collection.fetch();
},
addAll:function(models){
    models.each(function(model){
        console.log(model);
    })
    console.log(models.toJSON());
},
```

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Catalog of events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) in docs, it says that arguments being passed to collection's `add` event handler are `(model, collection, options)`, so `model` won't have `each` method with it. May be you can listen to `reset` event as the arguments being passed for that are `(collection, options)`.

Then you should be able to do `models.each` in `addAll` method.

Comment: i updated to like this "this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.addOne);" - but i am not get the collection. only the "add" - alone works.

Comment: When you said `this.addOne` instead of `this.addAll`, is there any other method like `addOne` or was that a typo ?

Comment: yes, addOne is the type issue. i use the "sync" - instead of "reset" - works fine. thanks for extending your great help.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like the collection is passed to your addAll method as an actual collection but as an array?

What does `console.log(typeof models)` do?

If you bind the eventhandler to `this` you can access the collection that way.

```
initialize:function(){

        var that = this;
        this.collection = headerCollection;

        this.collection.on("add", this.addAll, this);

        this.collection.fetch();


    },
    addAll:function() {

        this.collection.each(function(model){
            console.log(model);
        })

        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    },
```

I am not familiar with the listenTo method so I don't know what that does.

Comment: It giving 36 - models, instead of 6 models... and i used the "sync" - instead of "add" - giving 6 models as expected. thanks

Comment: Yeah, it gives 36 instead of 6 because it will trigger an add-event every time you add a model to the collection, so it gets called repeatedly. Sync on the other hand is called once a collection is done synchronizing its state with the server, e.g. after a call to Collection.sync has finished. (This is why it is often not a good idea to call render on a view in an add-event handler on a collection)